# How to solve 'pip install - syntax error'?

Tags: python

When i try to run this command `pip install pywhatkit`

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should i do?

Comment: Looks like your version of `pip` is not matching your version of `python`. You seem to run Python 3.5, but the f-strings that cause the syntax error were only introduced in Python 3.6.

Comment: This sounds like it's probably a bug in pywhatkit's versioning. It shouldn't attempt to install in Python 3.5.